# REACT library to display Twitter Search API results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter

I want to use the Twitter Search API to show tweets related to user searches in my React web application. Is there a React/Javascript library that can transform the API response and render the search results in a twitter feed style (e.g. all the HTML markup and styles)?

Any examples or pointers would be really helpful.

Comment: Do you found something? How you solve this?

Comment: Have a look a this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tweet. I managed to use this in the end.